# How can I declare an enum in wgsl?

Tags: rust, enums, voxel, octree, wgsl

I am trying to raymarch through a voxel octree on the gpu so I'm tyring to use an enum:

```
enum Node {
    Empty,
    Filled(ShaderVoxel),
    Group(array<Node>),
}
```

But this is telling me this:

```
error: expected global item ('struct', 'const', 'var', 'alias', ';', 'fn') or the end of the file, found 'enum'
   ┌─ wgsl:10:1
   │
10 │ enum Node {
   │ ^^^^ expected global item ('struct', 'const', 'var', 'alias', ';', 'fn') or the end of the file
```

Is there a different way of declaring it?
Or is it simply not supported?

If not is there another way to have an octree on the gpu in wgsl?
I am using bevy 0.12 on the cpu side of things

Comment: Why do you think `enum` is valid where you put it? I can't find any wgsl document stating that `enum`s are part of wgsl.

Comment: yeah thats what i was afraid of. i coudn't find anything either but just wanted to make sure.